# match.call called in wrong environment when eval’ing

Tags: r, eval, substitution

I tried implementing a function `let` with the following semantics:

```
> let(x = 1, y = 2, x + y)
[1] 3
```

… which is conceptually somewhat similar to `substitute` with the syntax of `with`.

The following code almost works (the above invocation for instance works):

```
let <- function (...) {
    args <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$`...`
    expr <- args[[length(args)]]
    eval(expr,
         list2env(lapply(args[-length(args)], eval), parent = parent.frame()))
}
```

Note the nested `eval`, the outer to evaluate the actual expression and the inner to evaluate the arguments.

Unfortunately, the latter evaluation happens in the wrong context. This becomes apparent when trying to call `let` with a function that examines the current frame, such as `match.call`:

```
> (function () let(x = match.call(), x))()
Error in match.call() :
  unable to find a closure from within which 'match.call' was called
```

I thought of supplying the parent frame as the evaluating environment for `eval`, but that doesn’t work:

```
let <- function (...) {
    args <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$`...`
    expr <- args[[length(args)]]
    parent <- parent.frame()
    eval(expr,
         list2env(lapply(args[-length(args)], function(x) eval(x, parent)),
                  parent = parent)
}
```

This yields the same error. Which leads me to the question: how exactly is `match.call` evaluated? Why doesn’t this work? And, **how do I make this work?**

Comment: Possibly relevant is this, from `?match.call`: "Calling 'match.call' outside a function without specifying 'definition' is an error." And then try `j <- function(x) x; j(match.call())` to see one place that error plays out. I haven't gamed this all out (and don't quite get what you're really trying to do), but this may be an error that's pretty specific to the odd way you're using `match.call()` in that call to an anonymous function.

Comment: @Josh I don’t think it’s related. The error message is different, and the context from which I call `match.call` is *definitely* from within a function, if the wrong one.

Comment: I guess what I was hinting at is that `match.call()` has pretty unique scoping rules that turn out to be specially hard-wired for it down at the C level. (The code defining `do_matchcall`, including some interesting comments about how the function it's called from is recorded, is in `$R_SRC/src/main/unique.c`.) Unlike almost any other function, it's not clear to me that it's evaluation environment can be manipulated/set via a call to `eval()`. To simplify your problem, maybe first figure out why this doesn't work (and how it could be made to): `j <- function() eval(call("match.call")); j()`.

Comment: @Josh Ah yes, agreed. Though R offers a surprising wealth of functions to access the scope and stack frames so I think that there might be a way to push this square peg into `eval`’s round hole.

Comment: That it does. For instance, this does work: `j <- function() do.call("match.call", list()); j()`, though I'd have thought it equivalent to the `j` in my last comment. Will be interested to see what someone comes up with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Will this rewrite solve your problem?

```
let <- function (expr, ...) {
    expr  <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$expr
    given <- list(...)
    eval(expr, list2env(given, parent = parent.frame()))
}

let(x = 1, y = 2, x + y)
# [1] 3
```

Comment: +1 -- Interesting that `match.call(expand.dots=FALSE)$"..."` and `list(...)` return different objects.

Comment: The arguments are in the wrong order here, and yet this appears to work. Could you explain **why** this works? I.e. why we can pass the expression as the *last* argument and still get it bound to the first? That said, this expression has the first problem as my first approach in that it doesn’t capture the parent scope … you need to explicitly pass `parent = parent.frame()` to `list2env`, despite this being the parameter’s default value, otherwise this won’t work: `(function (x) let(y=2, x+y))(1)`

Comment: @KonradRudolph -- That's just a consequence or [R's rules/algorithm for matching arguments](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/doc/manual/R-lang.html#Argument-matching). First the named arguments (here `x=1` and `y=2`) are processed, and neither of them has a name that matches the single named formal (`expr`). Then, as mentioned at the link above " Any unmatched formal arguments are bound to unnamed supplied arguments, in order." Here, that means `x + y` gets bound to `expr`.

Comment: @Josh Ah, of course. But that actually comes with a rather nasty consequence: I cannot use it with any expression which contains reference to an identifier `expr`. Hmm. I’ll need to change the argument name to something more obscure, it seems.

Comment: The use of the `.` prefix as in `.expr` is a pretty common approach to avoid such situations and keep meaningful variable names.

Comment: @KonradRudolph -- Even worse, the second rule on that linked list means that any argument named `e` or `ex` or `exp` will get matched to `expr`. Partial argument matching was IMHO a crummy design decision that's now +/- locked in by the many contributed functions that use it.

Comment: more reason to use `.expr`!

Comment: Another question: why use `match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$expr` instead of `substitute(expr)`?

Comment: @KonradRudolph -- Good question. The two **are** slightly different, if: (a) an object `expr` has been assigned to somewhere in the current evaluation environment (in which case `substitute()` will pick up that value rather than the value of the supplied argument) or (b) if you provide a default value for `expr` in the function definition and then supply no value for it in your function call. In case (b), `substitute(expr)` performs better, and case (a) can be easily avoided. Nitpicky differences, but interesting.